# How can I find out if a core-data object can be deleted when relationships could prevent it?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

Let's say I have an employee database, where an employee can be manager of a department. The manager relationship of a department (to an employee in the role of a manager) is not optional. So, I cannot delete an employee when he is manager of a deparment.

In my `UITableViewDelegate` I would like to have:

```
-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
          editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self mayDeleteTableView:tableView entryAtIndexPath:indexPath] ?
            UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete : UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
}
```

Where `mayDeleteTableView:entryAtIndexPath` returns `NO` when the employee is manager of a department, otherwise `YES`.

Now, of course I can implement this method by setting up a fetch request that tells me what I want. But I just wondered if there is an easier way than that, because core-data must have some mechanism to find out exactly this, otherwise it could not raise an error when I delete an object that I shouldn't.

<strike>So my question is: "Does core data offer the implementation of `mayDeleteTableView:entryAtIndexPath` for me somehow?"</strike>

**Update:** Ok, actually I found the `NSManagedObject:validateForDelete` method now. It seems to return always `NO`. So my question now is: "Do I have to implement `validateForDelete` or should this do the correct verification for me (in which case I am doing something else wrong)?"

Comment: Ok, I am doing something else wrong. In fact, using `validateForDelete` seems to be perfect.

Comment: If `validateForDelete:` returns NO, it should come with an associated error as to why.  What does the error say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set up the manager attribute as a BOOL or something similar, you can check your tableView against that.  After getting a reference to the employee through the tableView, something simple such as

```
return [[[fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] manager] boolValue] ? UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone : UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
```

Here I'm assuming you get the core data object via NSFetchResultsController, but no matter how you gather it, this should be the same logic.  I hope this helps

Comment: Ok, that sounds reasonable. If I set "managesDepartment" at employee to be the inverse relationship to the department's "manager" relationship, I could just check this for being empty. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, it might be a better idea to set up a BOOL property `isManager` for each employee.  I only say this because when saving your managedObjectContext, `nil` values tend to crash the system.  So if you set up a BOOL property, you will always have either `YES` or `NO`, so saving the context will be safe.  This should also let you use the code above in my answer instead of going through the `validateForDelete:` method

Comment: Well, it seems that validateForDelete does not work. I found out that it is also not intended for this use. See http://bit.ly/iWmdsq